# Access the menu structure in an application using visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to gain access to the menu structure information, such as the Name, handle and resource ID. Does anyone have a nice piece of code for doing this in visual C++ ?
I am trying to use the CMenu, GetSubMenu() and GetMenuString() options.

Many thanks in advance for your time.

```
void CConfigurationApp::FindMenuOptions()
{
BOOL    bOK = TRUE;

CString Level0;
CString Level1;
CString Level2;
CString Level3;
CString Level4;

long    MenuID  = 0;
long    LevelNo;
int     l0;
int     l1;
int     l2;
int     l3;
int     l4;
int     NoItems0;
int     NoItems1;
int     NoItems2;
int     NoItems3;
int     NoItems4;

CString csText;
CString Name;
CString Handle;

long ResourceID;

UINT    state;

CWnd*   pMain;
CMenu*  pMenu;

pMenu   = new CMenu;


//  Get Main Menu
pMain = AfxGetMainWnd();
if (pMain != NULL)
{
    // Get the main window's menu
    pMenu = pMain->GetMenu();
}

for (l0 = 0; l0 < pMenu->GetMenuItemCount(); ++l0)
{
    pMenu->GetMenuString(l0, csText, MF_BYPOSITION);

    CMenu*  pSubMenu1 = pMenu->GetSubMenu(l0);

    ++MenuID;
    LevelNo = 0;
    Level0  = csText;
    Level1  = "";
    Level2  = "";
    Level3  = "";
    Level4  = "";

    NoItems0    = pSubMenu1->GetMenuItemCount();
    if (NoItems0 < 0)
        NoItems0 = 0;

    Name    = "";
    Handle  = "";
    ResourceID  = 0;

    AddIntoMenuArray(MenuID, LevelNo, Level0, Level1, Level2, Level3, Level4, NoItems0, Name, Handle, ResourceID);

    for (l1 = 0; l1 < NoItems0; ++l1)
    {
        pSubMenu1->GetMenuString(l1, csText, MF_BYPOSITION);

        CMenu*  pSubMenu2 = pSubMenu1->GetSubMenu(l1);

        ++MenuID;
        LevelNo = 1;
        Level1  = csText;
        Level2  = "";
        Level3  = "";
        Level4  = "";

        NoItems1    = pSubMenu2->GetMenuItemCount();
        if (NoItems1 < 0)
            NoItems1 = 0;

        Name    = "";
        Handle  = "";
        ResourceID  = 0;

        AddIntoMenuArray(MenuID, LevelNo, Level0, Level1, Level2, Level3, Level4, NoItems1, Name, Handle, ResourceID);

        for (l2 = 0; l2 < NoItems1; ++l2)
        {
            pSubMenu2->GetMenuString(l2, csText, MF_BYPOSITION);

            CMenu*  pSubMenu3 = pMenu->GetSubMenu(l2);

            ++MenuID;
            LevelNo = 2;
            Level2  = csText;
            Level3  = "";
            Level4  = "";

            NoItems2    = pSubMenu3->GetMenuItemCount();
            if (NoItems2 < 0)
                NoItems2 = 0;

            Name    = "";
            Handle  = "";
            ResourceID  = 0;

            AddIntoMenuArray(MenuID, LevelNo, Level0, Level1, Level2, Level3, Level4, NoItems2, Name, Handle, ResourceID);

            for (l3 = 0; l3 < NoItems2; ++l3)
            {
                pSubMenu3->GetMenuString(l3, csText, MF_BYPOSITION);

                CMenu*  pSubMenu4 = pMenu->GetSubMenu(l3);

                ++MenuID;
                LevelNo = 3;
                Level3  = csText;
                Level4  = "";

                NoItems3    = pSubMenu3->GetMenuItemCount();
                if (NoItems3 < 0)
                    NoItems3 = 0;

                Name    = "";
                Handle  = "";
                ResourceID  = 0;

                AddIntoMenuArray(MenuID, LevelNo, Level0, Level1, Level2, Level3, Level4, NoItems3, Name, Handle, ResourceID);

                for (l4 = 0; l4 < NoItems3; ++l4)
                {
                    pSubMenu4->GetMenuString(l4, csText, MF_BYPOSITION);

                    ++MenuID;
                    LevelNo = 4;
                    Level4  = csText;
                    NoItems4    = 0;
                    Name    = "";
                    Handle  = "";
                    ResourceID  = 0;

                    AddIntoMenuArray(MenuID, LevelNo, Level0, Level1, Level2, Level3, Level4, NoItems4, Name, Handle, ResourceID);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

DeleteMenuArray();

delete  pMenu;
```

Comment: Please provide some code that you have already tried to get help easily

Comment: Though I do not support questions like this i.e..you need to do some homework prior to asking a question, I can provide you with a link that suits the question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365459/how-to-get-submenu-in-mfc

Comment: Apologies for not supplying the code, I should have known better. The not so sophisticated code i have been using to to get an idea on how the menu structure works is in the original post above. I can get some of the menu structure, but it does not work perfectly. Many thanks.